# Using JSON patch request to set Many-to-Many field as null

Tags: json, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have `Painting`s which can have many `Color`s:

```
# models
class Color(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(blank=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)

class Painting(models.Model):
  colors = models.ManyToManyField(Color)
  ...
```

I want to be able to `patch` the `Color`s that a `Painting` has:

```
# serializers
class PaintingUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  colors = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Color.objects.all(), allow_null=True)
  ...

  class Meta:
    model = Painting
    fields = ["colors", ...]

  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    colors = validated_data.pop("colors", [])
    if colors:
      instance.colors.set(colors)
    fields = [...]
    for field in fields:
      try:
        setattr(instance, field, validated_data[field])
      except KeyError:
        pass
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

This works fine when I'm adding or updating `Color`s to a `Painting` via JSON e.g. `{ colors: ["red", "blue"] }`

**But what do I do if I'm trying to *remove* all `Colors` from a `Painting`?**

What does my JSON payload need to look like? Do I need to update the `update` method in my serializer?

I considered doing:

```
  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    colors = validated_data.pop("colors", [])
    if colors:
      instance.colors.set(colors)
    else:
      instance.colors.set(None)
    ...
```

But since this is a `patch` request, there will be times where I'm updating other fields and leaving `Color` alone - and I don't want `Color` to be set to `None` then.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked:

1. Update `ManyToMany` field to include `blank = True`
2. Use empty array for JSON i.e. `color: []`
3. Use the following for the `update` method:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
  colors = validated_data.pop("genres", [])

  if len(colors) == 0:
    instance.colors.set("")
  elif colors:
    instance.colors.set(colors)
```